How to compile go project on pcc32
How to compile go project on ppc32
Known go support for ppc64
Known go not support for ppc32
Known gccgo can compile Single .go
I want to compile a go project on ppc32
I want use the go toolchain. for example go mod on ppc32

pcc32 is not currently a supported architecture; there is an open issue re ppc32 support. gcc-go may work. Not really sure what answer you are looking for here? (the OS will be a factor too)

Thanks for the answer. I used gccgo on ppc32 to compile  .go successfully(no go mod). I want to compile complex go projects, what are the options?
